# Salesforce API: Save email communication

Tags: python, salesforce

I am completely new to the Salesforce REST API and am looking for the best way to save email communication with a customer. I am accessing the mailbox programmatically and can't forward the email to the email2salesforce address. So somehow I will have to replicate this process through the API. Any ideas on where to start would be appreciated. I'm using Python as language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the customer you are communicating with will be represented as a Lead or Contact in Salesforce. If this is the case, then you probably want to store the emails in an Activity History. This is what happens if you send the email via the UI.

In reality it is storing a [Task](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm) record with:

- the `WhoId` field set to the Contact Id
- the `Subject` of "Email: " followed by the emails subject line.
- the `ActivityDate` of the current date.
- the `Status` Completed.
- the `Description` with other details about the email, such as any CC or BCC values.

With the REST API you will want `/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/task/`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that explains most of what I'd like to know. Then I guess this would have to preceded by a call to check if the contact exists (basically querying for the WhoId based on the email address), right?

Comment: @Vincent Yes, you will need the Contact.Id field to pass to the WhoId field on the Task. You can use a SOQL query along the lines of `Select Id from Contact where Email = 'foo@bar.com'` to find any matching Contacts. You might need to think about how to handle multiple Contacts with the same email address.

Comment: Where would you put the body at?  Poking around it looked like the body was stored in the description.  Is that the best way to handle this?